# How to create sql using IN condition include two columns (doma)

Tags: java

I use [Doma](https://doma.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

then, I want to create sql like below.

```
select * from 
table 
where (col1, col2) in (('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'));
```

can I do this? Do you know anything to solve it ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with Doma Criteria API.

See my example:

https://github.com/nakamura-to/getting-started/blob/in-condition/java-8/src/main/java/boilerplate/java8/repository/EmployeeRepository.java#L31-L32

The above example issues the following sql statement:

```
select t0_.id, t0_.name, t0_.age, t0_.version from Employee t0_ where (t0_.id, t0_.version) in ((1, 0), (2, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found Qiita article that you wrote. I gonna see that one too!